# summing inner product of orthonomal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

I need some help with some very basic linear algebra when doing calculations in inner product space.

Here is a line I got lost when reading a book...
\begin{align*}
(x,e_m)=\left(\sum_{n=1}^k\lambda_n e_n,e_m\right)=\sum_{n=1}^k\lambda_n \left(e_n,e_m\right)=\lambda_m,\quad m=1,\cdots, k.
\end{align*}

Could anyone show me explicitly how $\sum_{n=1}^k\lambda_n \left(e_n,e_m\right)=\lambda_m?$

I got $\sum_m\lambda_m$ here.

Comment: You incorrectly assumed $(e_n,e_m)$ is always $1$. Perpendicular basis vectors have inner product $0$.

Comment: I do know $(e_n,e_m)=0$ when $n\neq m$...But

Comment: Actually, what does $\sum_m \lambda_m$ even mean? You don't get to sum over $m$, the letter $m$ refers to a fixed number. If $m=1$ for instance, you've written down $\sum_1 \lambda_1$.

Comment: I wanted to write a way without testing out specific $k$ and $m$.

Comment: Sure. Then $$\sum_{n=1}^k \lambda_n\langle e_n,e_m\rangle=\left(\sum_{n<m} \lambda_n\langle e_n,e_m\rangle\right)+\lambda_m\langle e_m,e_m\rangle+\left(\sum_{n>m} \lambda_n\langle e_n,e_m\rangle\right)$$ $$=\left(\sum_{n<m}0\right)+\lambda_m+\left(\sum_{n>m}0\right)=\lambda_m. $$

Comment: Would be good if you  add that to your answer.

Comment: Using words is much better. Explain to your reader, using words, that "each term in the summand is $0$ except for the $\lambda_m$ term." That is much easier to digest then a hodge podge of symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e_1,\cdots,e_k$ is an orthonormal basis then $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle$ is $1$ when $i=j$ and $0$ when $i\ne j$.

Consider the case with $k=4$ and $m=3$. We have

$$\lambda_1\langle e_1,e_3\rangle+\lambda_2\langle e_2,e_3\rangle+\lambda_3\langle e_3,e_3\rangle+\lambda_4\langle e_4,e_3\rangle  $$

$$=\lambda_1\cdot0+\lambda_2\cdot0+\lambda_3\cdot1+\lambda_4\cdot0=\lambda_3. $$

Answer (score 2):

For an orthonormal basis, $(e_n,e_m) = \delta_{nm}$. $\delta_{nm} = 1$ when $n=m$ and $0$ when $n\neq m$. What happens when you plug this into your sum?